# Phonegap - Open App by uri

Tags: cordova, uri

I´m new with Phonegap but it´s a good way for me as an webdev. I´ve read about uri-scheme to open an app by uri (e.g. getting uri by QR-Code or in a mail). But I can´t bring this to live.

My device is an WP7.
The article: [how do I open iphone apps via phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851346/how-do-i-open-iphone-apps-via-phonegap) and this part of the documentation: https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml#url_schemes says it´s working only in iOS.

Is there any way to open my Phonegap App out of the mail order by scanning an QR-Code. And how can I use the parameters in the url?

```
Uri: myappx://domain.com?para=123
```

I´m using the actual latest environment but with a WP7.

Comment: Just a question. Can we directly open our application in PhoneGap using URL? If yes, which is the URL for our application?