# Switch to phone's native Contacts (view) app from PhoneGap/Cordova app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, contacts

Is there a way to open iOS/Android native Contacts application to show some specific contact?

I'm creating a Phonegap app that uses phone's contact list via the `contacts` plugin API. For users convenience I have a [Show contact] button that should switch to a native Contacts application on that specific contact.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Comment: Yes I have. Bounty questions tend to be up for few days so more people are motivated to post their answers.

Comment: That's fine. I just want to know if my research question has helped.

Comment: there is no way of doing this

Comment: @tillda Any luck with the bounty?

Answer (score 5):

Use a plug-in to go native via the browser javascript code. Here is an [excellent guide for building a custom PhoneGap plugin for iOS](http://moduscreate.com/building-a-custom-phonegap-plugin-for-ios/). Its very well documented and you will find a lot of screenshots of every step.

If you want to go deep about the subject i recomend you to read this two documents in order:

1. [Apache Cordova Plugin Development Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html)
2. [Apache Cordova iOS Plugins](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins)

If you need more assistance and have a more specific question i will be happy to help.

Comment: Do you know for sure that it is possible to open a specific contact in the Contacts app by writing it as a native plugin in ObjC/Swift?

Comment: Once you call your native code you can do whatever you need. Use the ABPersonViewController class of the Address Book UI framework, it implements the view used to display a person record but remember that person view controllers must be used with a navigation controller in order to function properly. You can read a step by step explanation of the process and download the source of a full working example app here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/UI_Controllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH5-SW1

Comment: this is how the cordova plugin works, it let you choose the contact from the list, but you can't open the contacts app. There is no point of doing your own plugin, you can't open the contacts app

Comment: With ABPersonViewController you need to set the displayedPerson property to the person record you want to display, its not true that the user needs to choose anything. That happens with the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController which i didnt quote. The op asked for a way to switch from a browser phone app to a native contacts application on a specific contact. I presented a solution to do exactly that.

Comment: but you get the data of the person, you don't switch to the contacts app, the cordova contacts plugin already use ABPersonViewController

Comment: I have installed contacts plugin in android. How can i open the mobile contacts list

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered before here: [how do I open iphone apps via phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851346/how-do-i-open-iphone-apps-via-phonegap)

> "The only way that one app, PhoneGap-based or otherwise, can cause
>   another app to launch is to open an URL "

**Opening Contacts:**

You would need a "URL scheme" such as the one defined here:

```
// In config.xml
<gap:url-scheme>
    <scheme>app1scheme</scheme>
</gap:url-scheme>
Then from your other app you'll just have a link to app1scheme://, eg simply

<a href="app1scheme://">Start App1</a>
```

**Contacts Database:**

If you have not  already, you can access the "Contacts database" using PhoneGap:

```
iOS (in the named application directory's config.xml)

<feature name="Contacts">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVContacts" />
</feature>
```

Source: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#Contacts

**Another Example, without PhoneGap(accessing the Calender):**

```
<a href="calendar://">Click me!</a>

Now go to your iOS app's info.plist file. In that add the following tags:

<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>com.companyname.appname</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>calendar</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</array>
Save the plist file and exit it. After this when you open the web page in Safari browser of your iOS device and click on the link, your iOS app will invoke. I hope it helps!
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7658785/950427

Comment: Is there some way to opem a specific contact (for example by its id) in the Contacts app?

Comment: @tillda That is a good question. I am not sure about specific contacts. Check this PhoneGap example, why not access the data directly and keep them in your app? http://devcenter.appery.io/tutorials/using-the-contacts-component/.

Comment: You have basically performed a google search. That's not research. Have you worked with PhoneGap/Cordova before? You said: "You would need a "URL scheme" such as the one defined here". No. The URL scheme would have to be defined by the application: in this case, Android's Contacts app & iOS's Contacts app - user tillda clearly cannot modify system apps and add these schemes. If these schemes were already defined, and you would have found them, that would be research! Downvoted.

Comment: Ouch. I was just trying to help. You should calm down. Why waste your time? You will hurt your reputation more than it will hurt mine.

Comment: @Athena is right, this answer doesn't provide any valuable information and doesn't answer the question at all. I can believe it got 3 upvotes.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Once again, I was just try to aggregate important information that would help lead someone to the correct answer.